# Irrelevant integral stdin input after 15000 array index in c++

Tags: c++, input, cin

I am trying to solve a problem in **c++,** that requires integral input to be read from **stdin** and to be stored in an array for further processing.

The input test case contains integers between 1 and 100000.
**The test case size is greater than 20,000,** but I found that after taking input beyond 15000  index , the input returns irrelevant,repetitive numbers like this -

94991  -(index)  19001
94991  -(index)  19002
94991  -(index)  19003
94991  -(index)  19004
94991  -(index)  19005
94991  -(index)  19006
94991  -(index)  19007
94991  -(index)  19008
94991  -(index)  19009
94991  -(index)  19010
94991  -(index)  19011

Whereas the original test case contains separate and different integers for the same.

Below is the code snippet for the input part-

```
int n,k,i=0;
    cin>>n;
    //taking input size of array
    int ar[n];

while(n--)
{
    cin>>k;
    ar[i]=k;

    if(i>15000)
    cout<<k<<"  -(index)  "<<i<<endl;


    ++i;
}
```

**Edit**
1) The problem persists even using a while loop without using an array, like in the below code snippet, just parsing input with variable k;
**Even use of vector renders false results.**

```
 cin>>n;
while(n--)
{

    //cin.clear();
    cin>>k;

    if(i>19000)
    cout<<k<<"  -  "<<i<<endl;

    ++i;
}
```

**The link for above input file  is** http://bit.ly/1PgAjB3 , any one of you can use this to test on ideone.

**2) The program works well for test cases at around 5000**

**The whole code of which the above snippet is a part of is ** http://ideone.com/WOYkEl

and you can see the code works when the test case is 5733

Comment: How are you generating your input, Are you actually manually typing in 15000 int variables? Also this code doesn't even compile.

Comment: here's a hint: check if `cin>>k` fails

Comment: What's the question/problem?

Comment: Could you upload the input file somewhere? This is a blind shot, but try with `long long int`

Comment: The input file can be seen here (http://bit.ly/1PgAjB3), I dont require solution to the coding question of which this snippet is a part, I just want to know why the input from stdin is working when test cases is <15000, and not beyond 15000.

Comment: There is no point in using long long int as all integers in the input are less than 100000;

Comment: could not reproduce. Tested `Edit1` on `gcc-4.8` `i>19000` Last numbers all match.

Comment: Last numbers all matched according to input?

Comment: I removed the first line of your file, otherwise n=10, tested the first 39385 numbers, checked the last 20, all match. Your input seems to be too big for ideone.

Comment: Which ide you used to check if not ideone?

Comment: no ide, plain gcc and text editor on a linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
int ar[n];
```

with

```
int * ar = new int[n];
```

At compile time you don't know `n`, so this requires dynamic allocation.

Comment: Even when I dont use an array just parse the integers using the variable k, the input from stdin starts being weird after 12000 test cases.